# Resizing window with keeping content proportion

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to let the user resizing the window but also to keep content in that window in one proportion. When the user sets window proportion which is different than content proportion on the (left and right) or (up and bottom)  I want to place bars. I don't know how to exactly describe my problem so I show image:

[image: Resizning image]

I want to do it with keeping MVVM architecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this simply by putting the sized (you can set `Width` and `Height` here to set the ratio) content inside a [ViewBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx) setting its [Stretch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.stretch.aspx) to [Uniform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch.aspx):

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
    <!-- Set Width and Height if required -->
    <TextBox Text="Hello world"/>
</Viewbox>
```